# How to load updated docker image onto other machine

Tags: docker

I have 2 hosts running the same docker customized image. I have modified the image on host 1 and saved the image to a custom.tar. If I take that image and load it onto host 2 will it just update or should I remove the old docker image first?

Comment: Not an answer to your direct question, but I would highly recommend using a container registry like DockerHub or other to distribute images between hosts and environments. "When in Rome"...

Comment: That  is almost an answer to the question. "Run your own registry" is a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do that with repository and without repository using load and save.

**With repository below are the steps.**

1. Log in on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/)
2. Click on Create Repository.
3. Choose a name  and a description for your repository and click
   Create.
4. Log into the Docker Hub from the command line

   `docker login --username=yourhubusername --email=youremail@company.com`
5. tag your image

   `docker tag <existing-image> <hub-user>/<repo-name>[:<tag>]`
6. Push your image to the repository you created

   `docker push <hub-user>/<repo-name>:<tag>`
7. Pull the image to host 2

   *`docker pull <hub-user>/<repo-name>:<tag>`*

   This will add the image to docker hub and available on internet and now you can pull this image to any system. 
   With this approach you can keep the same images with different tags on system. **But if you  don't need old images better to delete that to avoid junk.**

   **Without docker hub.**
8. This command will create tar bundle.

   `docker save [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]`

   example: `docker save busybox > busybox.tar`
9. Load an image from a tar archive or STDIN

   `docker load [OPTIONS]`

   example:`docker load < busybox.tar.gz`

**Recommended: Docker hub or DTR  approach easy to manage unless you have bandwidth issue in case your file is large.**

Refer:
[Docker Hub Repositories](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/)

Comment: This just tells me how to load, but did not answer the question.

Comment: @TimR how do you make your docker stack up? using docker-compose or somethign similar ??

Comment: Effectively I did a docker save on host 2, did a docker load on host 1, modified the image on host 2, did a docker save on host 1, and then did a docker load on host 2 and it worked just fine.

Comment: But in real CI/CD world we mainly prefer repository approach. We use DTR. We can implement same using docker hub.